# Should I standardize b-splines in a regression model?

Tags: regression, standardization, splines

I am fitting a non-linear regression model with 3 covariates $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$. The covariates $x_1$ and $x_2$ have linear effects, and $x_3$ covariate has a non-linear effect using a b-spline with 5 degrees of freedom.

The covariates $x_1$ and $x_2$ are standardised (zero mean, unit variance, in R using the command `scale`) because they can take large values and they create problems in my implementation (NB: this is not a $y = x\beta$ regression, but a slightly more complicated model).

**Question**: Should I also standardize the columns of the matrix of splines associated to $x_3$?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What is your goal in standardizing? Why standardize any of the features at all?

Comment: @Dave Thanks. It is because they can take very large values and they are creating problems in my implementation (it is not a simple linear regression model, but a sort of additive model based on a distribution like GAMLSS).